# Upgrade Angular 1.4 to greater

Tags: angularjs

I have the below project structure. I am trying to upgrade the project to higher version.
[image: Project Structure]

I need suggestions on using ngUpgrade.

Comment: I watched a talk on upgrading AngularJs to Angular. When she finished I said I would have started again that looked very painful. She said so would I if my employer would have allowed it. I think unless you designed your AngularJs components with an upgrade in mind your best path is running up a new Angular 10 app and recreating components from scratch.

Comment: Even with the first few Angular 2 apps I worked on I would create a brand new Angular 10 project and copy over components rather than try and use ng upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just finish upgrading AngularJs 1.4 application with over 50 directives and 90 services to Angular 8.

The approach I took is as follows:

1. If you are using a bundler that isn't webpack(e.g requireJs), first migrate to webpack.
   [link to article how to upgrade webpack from requireJs for example](http://j-query.blogspot.com/2015/06/from-requirejs-to-webpack-part-1-reasons.html)
2. Create a new Angular project that will live side by side with your 1.4 one:

```
Project
-app  // Your AngularJs app
--Controllers
--Services
--etc..
-ng_app // Your Angular app
--Components
--Services
--etc..
angular.json
webpack.config.js
Global.asax
packages.config
```

3. Change `angular.json` builders to work with [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) so you could compile your two application - Meaning your Hybrid application - with your webpack configuration and Angular injected configuration.
4. Start [Upgrading AngularJs services and directives](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade). At this point your AngularJs application should be bootstrapped first.
   You'll still Bootstrap your AngularJs app from Angular via:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}
```

But the main idea here is that `@NgModule` for `AppModule` won't contain `bootstrap` configuration. Only `entryComponents` (if you are using angular version8 and less) that will be opened from your AngularJs application via downgraded statements.

5. After you upgraded enough services and components, switch Angular to bootstrap first, and bootstrap AngularJs lazily.
   Here you should bootstrap Angular first. It means to also populate the `bootstrap` configuration in `@NgModule` `AppModule` with `AppComponent`.
6. Finish upgrading all AngularJs services and directives.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I am stuck at step 4 . Created new app with latest Angular version. But, bootstrapping old version is where I am confused. Is there any sample solution I can use ?

Comment: "bootstrapping old version" is just the bootstrap line I outline in code snippet. Where are you exactly stuck? Do you get an error?